# Rails: non matching asset digests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Below is the asset host config of my Rails app

```
ASSET_HOSTS = ["http://host1.cdn.com", "http://host2.cdn.com"]

config.asset_host = proc do |path, request=nil, *_|
  ASSET_HOSTS.sample
end
```

The problem with this is that one of my javascript files (which is a .js.erb file) has a different digest (when called by javascript_include_tag) than the one specified in manifest.yml (generated during precompilation).

Does anyone know why this happened and how to fix it?